# Div Alignment Issues

Tags: html, css, alignment

I just came back from a 10 year hiatus of web design.  I'm getting close to knowing the in's and out's of div properties (those weren't as popular back in my day as they are now).  Right now I'm trying to get a layout like this:

Logo | Icons Div
Banner Div
Link Div
Content Div
Footer Div

My issue at the moment is centering the Link Div, which is:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a class="link1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="link2" href="#">About Us</a>
    <a class="link3" href="#">Services</a>
    <a class="link4" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="link5" href="#">Contant Us</a>
</div>
```

The CSS that I'm using:

```
.menu   
    {
        TO BE USED
    }

.menu a
    {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        line-height: 144px;
        margin: 5px;
        opacity: 0.3;
        text-align: center;
        width: 144px;
    }

.link1
    {
        background: #fdd22a;
    }

.link2
    {
        background: #009fe3;
    }

.link3
    {
        background: #574696;
    }
.link4
    {   
        background: #ee7202;
    }
.link5
    {
        background: #e61c67;
    }
.link6
    {
        background: #96c11f;
    }
```

Here's a sample of what I'm doing: http://www.ragnarok.ws.

At the moment, I don't have enough links (or knowledge) to align the links with the left and right margins (line up with the left side of the logo and right side of the social media icons) to a point where it doesn't look spread out and silly, so I figured my next best option is to try and center the divs for the link.  The coding I linked is also a bit rough.  I haven't had a chance to go and clean things up, yet.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your css remove the float: left;

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left` from `.menu` and `.menu a` and just add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to `.menu` to make the links centered.

Also, change your `display` from `block` to `inline-block` for `.menu a`

Remember to give a width for `.menu`. I just tried a width of `61%` via Inspect Element and it got right.

**OR**

Add

```
text-align: center;
```

to `.menu`

and change your `display` from `block` to `inline-block` for `.menu a`.

**No need for specifying width for `.menu` in this method.** May be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you, Lal.  Your second option seem to be the easiest to configure.  I'm going to play around with it, but I wanted to say thank you.

Comment: @RalphLucianoPadroJr. Great.. :) please ask me if any doubts..meanwhile please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you..

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Learn CSS Layout](http://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html):

```
   .menu
    {
       width: 600px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

> Setting the `width` of a block-level element will prevent it from
>   stretching out to the edges of its container to the left and right.
>   Then, you can set the left and right margins to `auto` to horizontally
>   center that element within its container. The element will take up the
>   width you specify, then the remaining space will be split evenly
>   between the two margins.

Comment: Can you explain *why* this works. A link to documentation **in addition** would also be useful.